# timestamp conversion error in R: Error in unclass(x)/86400 : non-numeric argument to binary operator

Tags: r

My dataset is read from csv and it is quite big. I have many fields of timestamp attributes, all imported as character variables. When trying to convert these to dates and calculate difference in seconds, I ran into such error in only 1 of the timestamp variables:

Date imported:

```
ID  clicked_at  bounced_at  retrieved_at    dropped_at
323232  4/23/16 02:13   4/23/16 02:14   4/23/16 02:16   4/23/16 02:16
323582  3/29/16 19:00   3/29/16 19:00   3/29/16 19:03   3/29/16 19:04
235302  6/21/16 11:56   6/21/16 11:56   6/21/16 12:01   6/21/16 12:01
```

Code used to convert timestamp:

```
test$bounce_speed <- as.POSIXct(test$bounced_at) - as.POSIXct(test$clicked_at)
```

Error got:

```
Error in unclass(x)/86400 : non-numeric argument to binary operator
```

After testing, I believe the problem is in `retrieved_at` variable. I used the same code to calculate lag between other variables here, all ran okay. But just by eye-balling, I could not find anything wrong in `retrieved_at`, and my data size is huge. My guess is some records have irregular formats, but how to fix this here?

Comment: Have you found a solution? I am running into the exact same issue.